# Rounding up and rounding down in excel

Tags: excel, integer, rounding

I don't know how to round up and round down in excel if I have variety of numbers.
For ex: If I have 9.233, then it rounds down to 9 because 0.233 < 0.5, but if it is 2.457, then it rounds up to 3 because 0.457 = 0.5 (if you round it), and then if I have 3.890, then it rounds up to 4 because 0.890 >= 0.5.

I don't know what to do. I tried:
=IF(A1-INT(A1)>0.1,ROUNDUP(A2,0),INT(A2))

but it doesn't work.
Please help

Comment: I don't see that behavior at all... What happens when you calculate "=ROUND(2.457,0)" ? I get 2.

Comment: Why are you testing A1 then Rounding A2?  Shouldn't it be the same cell: `=IF(A1-INT(A1)>0.1,ROUNDUP(A1,0),INT(A1))`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just the **ROUND(, 0)** for your purpose.
This should yeild the desired result.

**Num**         **Rounded Num**
-----------------------
9.233         9
2.457         2
3.89           4

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!